# how to convert mongodb queries into java

Tags: java, mongodb-java

how to convert mongodb queries  into java

I want to convert following query into java

```
db.Student.aggregate( {$group : {_id : "$prnno", x: {$push:"$name"} , st:{$push: "$per"} }},
                      {$sort:{st:-1} },{$limit:3});
```

Comment: Could you please post code for your best attempt? Thanks

Comment: I want to find first 3 toppers with their name and percentage

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I hope it helps:

```
collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList({$or:[
        new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("x", {$push:"$name"})),
        new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("st", {$push: "$per"}))],
        new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("st", -1)),
        new BasicDBObject("$limit", 3)))
```